# MySQL Unique, Index, and Fulltext indexing. All together or one is enough?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-indexing, unique-index

I wanted to have one specific column be unique and also optimized for searching and sorting. Meanwhile the same column should have fulltext search capability. Should I add all three indexing types (Unique, Index, and Fulltext) together on this column or not?

Please help and thanks.

--Edit

Thanks @Fuujin for the quick comment.

What if I have the following indexing, no need for adding "Index" indexing anymore on neither of them, right?

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE (`column_1`, `column_2`);
```

Comment: Already answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393234/mysql-unique-field-need-to-be-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393234/mysql-unique-field-need-to-be-index)

Comment: Thanks. So, only "Index" indexing is redundant, right?

Comment: as I understand it: yes. Here is even more information: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

One column:

```
UNIQUE(x)
FULLTEXT(x)
```

Adding `INDEX` would be redundant, since `UNIQUE` *is* an `INDEX`.

Two columns:

```
UNIQUE(x,y)  -- the order depend on what your queries look like (see below)
FULLTEXT(x,y)
FULLTEXT(x), FULLTEXT(y) -- may need these (see below)
```

`WHERE x > 5 AND y = 2` needs `(y,x)` order

If you search only one of the two columns, such as `MATCH(x) AGAINST(...)`, then InnoDB, but not MyISAM, needs the extra `FULLTEXT` indexes.

Comment: Thanks @rick.
So, you're saying if I'm on MyISAM only `FULLTEXT(x,y)` would be enough for any fulltext searching?
Also ordering point you mentioned was not completely clear for me.

Comment: In a list of people ordered by `(last_name, first_name)`, you can quickly find `last_name='James' AND first_name LIKE 'R%'`, but it is much harder to find `first_name = 'Rick' AND last_name LIKE 'J%'`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also take a look at this question of me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267528/fulltext-indexing-on-myisam-single-column-vs-multiple-column-indexing